# mount fuse filesystem inside kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, fuse

I would like to mount a google drive inside my pod. I add:

```
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      capabilities:
        add:
        - SYS_ADMIN
```

to the pod. However, [google drive ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) mounts the data directory, but a simple command on the mounted file system results with a `Input/output error`.

Is it possible to mount a fuse filesystem inside a pod? Is there anything I need on the host?

Comment: Are you running this on GCP/GKE?

Comment: no; private kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Please, take a look [here](https://karlstoney.com/2017/03/01/fuse-mount-in-kubernetes/) and tell me if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [smarter-device-manager](https://gitlab.com/arm-research/smarter/smarter-device-manager)

We have a similar setup with what described in this blog post and I can confirm we can mount `/dev/fuse` device in unprivileged mode.
https://randomopenstackthoughts.wordpress.com/2021/03/12/how-to-mount-dev-fuse-without-privileged-mode-in-kubernetes/